# Error in CakePHP 3 when hashing passwords: hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given APP/Model/Entity/User.php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am following the official **bookmarker tutorial**: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html#bookmarker-tutorial

But after adding the **_setPassword($value)** method to my **User** class I am getting these warnings that prevent me to save the **hashed password** correctly in my **users** table.

```
Warning (2): hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given [APP/Model/Entity/User.php, line 26]
Warning (4096): Object of class Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher could not be converted to string [APP/Model/Entity/User.php, line 26]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: _SESSION [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 440]
```

- This is my method in **App\Model\Entity\User**:

```
    protected function _setPassword($value)
    {
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        return $hasher.hash($value);
    }
```

- My **password field** in the database has **255 of length** (some people reported having issues because of the length of the field in MySQL and the new encryption method used by CakePHP 3).
- My PHP version is PHP 5.5.20 (cli) (built: Feb 25 2015 23:30:53)
- In my **error.log** I see following lines:

```
2015-08-08 21:43:56 Warning: Warning (2): hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in [/Applications/AMPPS/www/projects/bookmarker/src/Model/Entity/User.php, line 26]
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 139
hash - [internal], line ??
App\Model\Entity\User::_setPassword() - APP/Model/Entity/User.php, line 26
Cake\ORM\Entity::set() - CORE/src/Datasource/EntityTrait.php, line 254
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::merge() - CORE/src/ORM/Marshaller.php, line 467
Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() - CORE/src/ORM/Table.php, line 2032
App\Controller\UsersController::edit() - APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 75
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 411
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 114
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37



2015-08-08 21:43:56 Warning: Warning (4096): Object of class Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher could not be converted to string in [/Applications/AMPPS/www/projects/bookmarker/src/Model/Entity/User.php, line 26]
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 139
App\Model\Entity\User::_setPassword() - APP/Model/Entity/User.php, line 26
Cake\ORM\Entity::set() - CORE/src/Datasource/EntityTrait.php, line 254
Cake\ORM\Marshaller::merge() - CORE/src/ORM/Marshaller.php, line 467
Cake\ORM\Table::patchEntity() - CORE/src/ORM/Table.php, line 2032
App\Controller\UsersController::edit() - APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 75
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 411
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 114
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 87
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 37
```

- The same happens when using the **Console**:

```
    ➜  bookmarker git:(master) ✗ bin/cake console

    Welcome to CakePHP v3.0.11 Console
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    App : src
    Path: /Applications/AMPPS/www/projects/bookmarker/src/
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    You can exit with `CTRL-C` or `exit`

    Psy Shell v0.5.2 (PHP 5.5.20 — cli) by Justin Hileman
    >>> $u = new App\Model\Entity\User;
    => App\Model\Entity\User {#212
         +"[new]": true,
         +"[accessible]": [
           "*" => true,
         ],
         +"[dirty]": [],
         +"[original]": [],
         +"[virtual]": [],
         +"[errors]": [],
         +"[repository]": null,
       }
    >>> $u->set('password', 'a password');
    PHP warning:  hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/AMPPS/www/projects/bookmarker/src/Model/Entity/User.php on line 26
    >>> $u->password
    => null
```

Comment: "return $hasher->hash($value);" not  "return $hasher.hash($value);"

Comment: Hi @Eugen, you are right! My bad; coming from Java syntax didn't help me :)

Comment: Password Hash did not work for me initially. I had to delete the user and then add again, to get the hash working.

Answer (score 0):

The method _setPassword should

```
 return $hasher->hash($value);
```

instead of

```
return $hasher.hash($value);
```